# how to configure my site to access from http to https using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, https, middleware

I am trying to configure my site for redirect from http to https.

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        if($this->app->environment('production')) {
          \URL::forceScheme('https');
     }
```

**.env**

```
APP_URL=https://127.0.0.1:8000
```

I created an HttpsProtocol file in the root

**App/Http/Middleware/HttpsProtocol.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HttpsProtocol {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
            if (!$request->secure()) {
               return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
            }

            return $next($request); 
    }
}
?>
```

**kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...
            ...
            \App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class,
        ],
```

**config/app.php**

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://localhost'),
```

when I enter by `https://127.0.0.1:8000/` it gives me This site is inaccessible

Comment: If you think that you must have **https** locally to test something then you may be approaching things wrong.

Comment: You need to install SSL on your local

Comment: Https usualy goes on port 443 and that's how most browsers expects. anyway, to setup https, you need to configure it in your server (apache or nginx) not only in your code.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: go to the host file and add this line this line

`127.0.0.1 site.test`

step 2: add `site.test` to `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
## site.test
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName site.test
     ServerAlias *.site.test
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName site.test
     ServerAlias *.site.test
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/site.test/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/site.test/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>
```

step 3: go to xampp\apache and create new directory `crt` (Our certificates will be stored in this folder)

We need two files in the `crt` folder, one file called cert.conf which you can download below, and another file called make-cert.bat which you have to create and write the following code in it

1 cert.conf : https://gist.github.com/mdobydullah/8037540214d80d5931fb18c31ebf3e97

2 make-cert.bat

```
@echo off
set /p domain="Enter Domain: "
set OPENSSL_CONF=../conf/openssl.cnf

if not exist .\%domain% mkdir .\%domain%

..\bin\openssl req -config cert.conf -new -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout %domain%\server.key -x509 -days 365 -out %domain%\server.crt

echo.
echo -----
echo The certificate was provided.
echo.
pause
```

Open the cert.conf file and search for "site.test", then replace it with your domain.
Double-click on the make-cert.bat file to open your terminal, then enter the required items and press Enter.[image]

step 4:
After performing the above steps, a folder inside the crt folder named `site.test` will be created, in which there are two files named `server.crt` and server.key, to install it on Windows on the `server.crt` file Double click, and install certificate

step 5:Finally we need to restart our Apache, then refresh the browser to see the green lock.